# Pyspark dataframe create new column from other columns and from it

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have pyspark dataframe DF

Now I would like create a new column with below condition.

city    customer    sales   orders  checkpoint

a       eee         20      20       1

b       sfd         28      30     0

C   sss 30  30  1

d   zzz 35  40  0

```
DF = Df.withColumn("NewCol",func.when(DF.month == 1,DF.sales + DF.orders).otherwise(greatest(DF.sales,DF.orders))+ func.when(DF.checkpoint == 1,lit(0)).otherwise(func.lag("NewCol).over(Window.partitionBy(DF.city,DF.customer).orderBy(DF.city,DF.customer))))
```

I got an error like NewCol is not defined which is expected.

Please suggest me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Created a column
    df= df.withColumn("NewCol",lit(None))

```
for i in range(2):
    if i<=2:
      DF = Df.withColumn("NewCol",func.when(DF.month == 1,DF.sales + DF.orders).otherwise(greatest(DF.sales,DF.orders))+ func.when(DF.checkpoint == 1,lit(0)).otherwise(func.lag("NewCol).over(Window.partitionBy(DF.city,DF.customer).orderBy(DF.city,DF.customer))))</i)
```